# How to filter request data by keys from in validation rules?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I am working on a multi-step registration form. In the first step, I need to collect `first_name`, `last_name`, and `dob`, then create a `Customer` object *with only those three fields*:

```php
// RegistrationController.php
public function store_profile(Request $request) {
    $rules = ['first_name' => '...', 'last_name' => '...', 'dob' => '...'];
    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    Customer::create($request);
}
```

The problem is that other fields, such as `address`, `city`, `state`, etc. are *also fillable*:

```php
// Customer.php
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'address', 'city', 'state', ...];
```

I intend to collect them in the second step of the registration (in `public function store_address()`), yet nothing will prevent the user from `POST`ing those additional fields to step one:

```php
// RegistrationController.php
public function store_profile(Request $request) {
    $rules = ['first_name' => '...', 'last_name' => '...', 'dob' => '...'];
    $this->validate($request, $rules); // won't validate 'address', 'city', 'state'

    Customer::create($request); // will store everything that's fillable,
                                // no matter if it was validated or not...
}
```

Hence, my goal is to filter `$request->all()` fields by the array keys defined in my validation `$rules` variable. Here's my attempt:

```php
$data = [];
foreach(array_keys($rules) as $key) {
    $val = $request->{$key};
    if (! empty($val))
        $data[$key] = $val;
}
// in the end, $data will only contain the keys from $rules
// i.e. 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob'
```

First, is there a more efficient/concise way to do it using `array_column` or `array_intersect_key` or other, possibly without manual looping? Second, is there a more Laravel-like approach that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about `only()` (and `except()`)?

`Customer::create($request->only(['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob']));`

or

`Customer::create($request->only(array_keys($rules)));`

Edit: In Laravel 5.5, there's [another solution](https://laravel-news.com/request-data-validator-improvements):

```
$rules = ['first_name' => '...', 'last_name' => '...', 'dob' => '...'];
$data = $this->validate($request, $rules);

Customer::create($data); // $data contains only first_name, last_name and dob
```

Comment: There could be a problem with `only()`. If you pass `['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob']`, and `$request` does not have `first_name` for some reason, Laravel will include `'first_name' => null` to the request. This may raise SQL exception "No default value" as it will try to insert `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, but you'll also get `NULL` if you get the input with `$request->input('first_name')`. Here, you could define a default value (`$request->input('first_name', 'John Doe')`). But I'd rather handle this in the model's `public setFirstNameAttribute($value)` method.

Comment: One way I got around that is to get the `$keys` using `array_intersect` on my `array_keys($rules)` and `array_keys($request->all())`. Then, I call `Customer::create($request->only($keys))` and this one seems safe, but hacky and non-obvious. Do you think there's a better way?

Comment: @Alex Maybe something like `array_filter($request->only([...]), 'isset')`? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

I would have done like this if I were you:

```
public function store_profile(Request $request) {
    $rules = ['first_name' => '...', 'last_name' => '...', 'dob' => '...'];
    $this->validate($request, $rules); // won't validate 'address', 'city', 'state'

    Customer::create([
        'first_name' => $request->input('first_name');
        'last_name'  => $request->input('last_name');
        'dob'        => $request->input('dob');
    ]); 

}
```

or even simpler:

```
Customer::create($request->only(['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob']));
```